# Effect plot with lme model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data, effects

I am building a mixed-effects model with nlme package.

The output of the model is as seen below, and includes the time variable, namely day and one categorical variable for treatment with 4 categories.. The reference category that is not shown here is ***treatedWT***. And of course the interaction between these 2 variables is included in the model as can be seen.

[image]

Now, I would like to plot this model and i found the function Effect in the package effects, which from what i understand does exactly that, but i cannot really understand how it does so. Does it take into account also the random part of the model? Because if you check the numbers you will confirm that these lines are not calculated only based on the fixed part.

Here is the Effect plot of the previous model:

[image]

And of course, if you know a better way to plot this nlme model it is also very welcome!
Thank you all for your time!

Comment: "Because if you check the numbers you will confirm that these lines are not calculated only based on the fixed part." I don't have time to calculate all lines but for ctl WT: 2.01 + 60 * 0.025 + 0.062 + 60 * 0.01 = 4.17 which seems to roughly match the plot. Can you please point out specific discrepancies you found?